# Sign an xml document with a certificate

Tags: xml, vb.net, x509certificate, sign

I need to sign this xml file ( https://www.dropbox.com/s/qfkfvkc83kt72mb/20381235051-01-FF11-04.xml ) with a x509 v3 certificate but the signature must be at affixed at this node:

Invoice/ext:UBLExtensions/ext:UBLExtension/ext:ExtensionContent (lines 19-20)

I found a code to sign an xml file but it's affixed at the end of the document, how shall i proceed?

Here is my code:

```
Dim f_adresse As String = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
Dim f_temp As String = f_adresse & "TEMP"
Dim f_fichier As String = "20381235051-01-FF11-04.xml"
Dim f_certificat As String = f_adresse & "aG9CcVpHVndCWTd3WlVOVw==.p12"
Dim f_pwd As String = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

Dim xmlFile As String = f_temp & f_fichier

Dim MonCertificat As X509Certificate2 = New X509Certificate2(f_certificat, f_pwd)

Dim xmlDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = True
xmlDoc.Load(xmlFile)

Dim signedXml As SignedXml = New SignedXml(xmlDoc)

Dim KeyInfo As KeyInfo = New KeyInfo()
Dim Reference As Reference = New Reference()
Reference.Uri = ""

Reference.AddTransform(New XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform())

signedXml.AddReference(Reference)

Dim X509Chain As X509Chain = New X509Chain()
X509Chain.Build(MonCertificat)

Dim local_element As X509ChainElement = X509Chain.ChainElements(0)
Dim x509Data As KeyInfoX509Data = New KeyInfoX509Data(local_element.Certificate)
Dim subjectName As String = local_element.Certificate.Subject

x509Data.AddSubjectName(subjectName)
KeyInfo.AddClause(x509Data)

signedXml.KeyInfo = KeyInfo
signedXml.ComputeSignature()

Dim signature As XmlElement = signedXml.GetXml()

For Each node As XmlNode In signature.SelectNodes("descendant-or-self::*[namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#']")
    node.Prefix = "ds"
    If node.LocalName = "Signature" Then
        Dim newAttribute As XmlAttribute = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("Id")
        newAttribute.Value = "SignatureSP"
        node.Attributes.Append(newAttribute)
     End If
Next node


xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(signature, True))
xmlDoc.Save(xmlFile)
```

Thanks

Edit:
At the end of my code but doesn't work:

```
For Each node As XmlNode In signature.SelectNodes("descendant-or-self::*[namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#']")
    node.Prefix = "ds"
    If node.LocalName = "Signature" Then
        Dim newAttribute As XmlAttribute = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("Id")
        newAttribute.Value = "SignatureSP"
        node.Attributes.Append(newAttribute)
     End If
Next node

Dim signNode As XmlNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/tns:Invoice/ext:UBLExtensions/ext:UBLExtension/ext:ExtensionContent")
If Not signNode Is Nothing Then
    signNode.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(signature, True))
End If

xmlDoc.Save(xmlFile)
```

Answer (score 0):

Get that node then append. If you have to load the Namespaces:

```
Dim nsMgr As XmlNamespaceManager
nsMgr = New XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable)
nsMgr.AddNamespace("sac", "urn:sunat:names:specification:ubl:peru:schema:xsd:SunatAggregateComponents-1")
nsMgr.AddNamespace("ccts", "urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2")
nsMgr.AddNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
nsMgr.AddNamespace("tns", "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2")
nsMgr.AddNamespace("cac", "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2")
nsMgr.AddNamespace("udt", "urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2")
nsMgr.AddNamespace("ext", "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2")
nsMgr.AddNamespace("qdt", "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2")
nsMgr.AddNamespace("cbc", "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2")
nsMgr.AddNamespace("ds", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")

Dim signNodes = mlDoc.SelectNodes
    ("/tns:Invoice/ext:UBLExtensions/ext:UBLExtension/ext:ExtensionContent", nsMgr)

If signNodes.Count > 0 Then
 signNodes(0).AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(signature, True))
End If
```

Comment: shall i replace the for loop by this code? how to find also the xpath value? i've tried /Invoice/ext:UBLExtensions/ext:UBLExtension/ext:ExtensionContent but that doesn't work. I've also to add the prefix "ds" to the signature node and to each child node

Comment: `Liquid XML` gives me this for the xpath for the collection so just get the first - {/tns:Invoice/ext:UBLExtensions/ext:UBLExtension/ext:ExtensionContent}

Comment: I tried the method you suggested me to try but doesn't work, it says the request has a prefix. I don't know if that can help or not, the ext:UBLExtensions node has 2 ext:UBLExtension childnodes

Comment: it makes no sense, the SelectNodes method returns an XmlNodeList element, the AppendChild and FirstChild methods ain't available. There is a thing I misunderstand in your code : how am I supposed to update my xmlDoc variable?

Comment: I was thinking of a different object.

Comment: I've no execution error but my xml file is not signed and my <sac:AdditionalMonetaryTotal> is duplicated. I just noticed one thing, my signature must be at this exact node:
Invoice/ext:UBLExtentions/ext:UBLExtention[2]/ext:ExtentionContent

Comment: Once you find the xpath for that then you attach the signature to it. At this point you need to experiment with the xpath til it finds it.

Comment: i took /tns:Invoice/ext:UBLExtensions[2]/ext:UBLExtension/ext:ExtensionContent as my xpath value but nothing changes on my xml file. Moreover, i still misunderstand your code : why don't you use the signature variable? it contains the signature of my document

Comment: Is it possible to talk about this prob on Skype ? Mine is roromulus001

Comment: Updated, and it works for me. I can't test the signature part but the xpath does work.